# Is "K&R C" still applicable

Tags: c

I relearning **`C`**; it's been years and whilst familiar the nuances are lost in time.

I originally learned **`C`** from K&R.  However, I now see many people levelling criticism at K&R.

A chief example is http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/learn-c-the-hard-waych55.html#x61-27200055

Top reasons seem to be that it's code style is overly terse, practises aren't applicable in larger programs and lead to memory leaks or are subject to attack in shared network accessible systems.

Do people feel these criticisms are fair?  Do they matter to somebody learning **`C`**?  If so, could people recommend a "modern" **`C`** book, preferably available for Kindle?

Comment: Most of all, K&R is from before the language was standardized, and it is from a time when the computer landscape looked quite different. It might be a nice second read, but perhaps there are better books for learning proper, modern C.

Comment: Voted to close because it's subjective, but just FYI I stopped reading after seeing that the first criticism can be summarised as "this function will cause problems if you pass it invalid parameters". If you think that's a "defect", you should switch to Java.

Comment: @Kerrek SB - K&R 2nd. Ed. covers standard C89.

Comment: Thank you all very much.  I'll continue with K&R and then look at the two books recommended.  Apologies for the inappropriate post; I'll read the FAQ again.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As long as you're talking about the 2nd Edition, K&R is still *very* relevant.

In fact, I would say it's still the very best single book on C, both for learning, and for reference.

That said, you should also get a copy of Harbison & Steele's "C: A Reference Manual". It's the  best current reference on C, and the Fifth Edition covers C99, which you should use if you can.

Also, once you've got a bit of C behind you, I'd strongly recommend reading "Expert C Programming", by Peter van der Linden.

Comment: What about C11? Is there no book on it?

Comment: Well, K&R 2nd Ed. is still applicable to C11, but no, I'm not aware of any book covering C11. Harbison & Steele's "C: A Reference Manual (5th Edition)" is the most up to date C book I'm aware of, but it only covers C99. I'm still hoping for a 6th Ed.

Comment: Wikipedia writes for [DragonFly BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DragonFly_BSD) "As with FreeBSD and OpenBSD, the developers of DragonFly BSD are slowly replacing K&R style C code with more modern, ANSI equivalents." Does this mean that much of the Kernel code for BSD Linux implementations predates C89?

Comment: There's a book by Jens Gustedt, which covers the latest standards: Modern C. I haven't read it yet. You can find it here: https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/

Answer (score 4):

It is still relevant and still very useful with regards to learning the language.  Learning the language doesn't require you to implement new practices or styles that assist in code readability, etc.

For example, the idea of self documenting code is that you use verbose variable and function names to help explain the purpose of a function or a variable.  K&R is clearly opposed to this.  That doesn't mean you can't learn the C language from K&R, it just means that your style will need to be adjusted/updated based on whatever naming convention you decide upon in the future.

I cannot recommend "Expert C Programming" enough (as stated by gregj).

Comment: after moving from C and Assembler I mainly use C++ and Java, so I think I can apply some of the generic good practices from those.  Could you suggest any references for C-specific good practices or would the books that gregj and you suggest cover that?

Comment: Sir, I am Confused Here, I am not native english speaker , what does "I can’t recommend the book enough." means , do you suggest Expert C Programming or not?

Comment: @SurajJain yes, that phrase means that I do not have enough ways to recommend the book to you.

Comment: @BrettMcLain Ok I will try to read that book, if it is so good, wont it be outdated.